# Matlab to python nested loops conversion

Tags: python, matlab, loops, list-comprehension

I'm converting a matlab model to python, with the goal of obtaining the same plot in python as in matlab. However, I'm stuck into loops conversion.

Here is a reproducible matlab code:

```matlab
%model data

Dt = 1;
T_oi=12;
K = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000];
for i=1:432
    k11(i)= 0.5;
    tao_o(i)= 210;
    R_tap(i) = 10.7491679273828;
    x(i)= 0.8;
    dT_or(i)= 52;
    T_a(i) = 20;
end

dt = (30:30:432*30);
T_o=[];

%model

for step=1:432

    if step==1
        for i=1:dt(step)  
            DT_o(i) = Dt/k11(step)/tao_o(step)*((((1+R_tap(step)*K(step)^2)/(1+R_tap(step)))^x(step))*dT_or(step)-(T_oi-T_a(step)));
            T_o(i) = T_oi + DT_o(i);
        end
    else
        for i=1:(dt(step)-dt(step-1))
            DT_o(i+dt(step-1)) = Dt/k11(step)/tao_o(step)*((((1+R_tap(step)*K(step)^2)/(1+R_tap(step)))^x(step))*dT_or(step)-(T_o(i+dt(step-1)-1)-T_a(step)));
            T_o(i+dt(step-1)) = T_o(i+dt(step-1)-1) + DT_o(i+dt(step-1));
        end
    end
end

figure(1) 
plot(T_o);
grid on
```

Below is my reproducible attempt in python.. I am aware that index starts at 0 in python, but no matter what i try in ranges, i always get 'IndexError: list assignment index out of range' on the DT_o[i] calculation.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# model data, feel free to ignore
Dt = 1
T_oi = 12
K = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000]
k11=[0.5]*432
tao_o=[210]*432
R_tap=[10.7491679273828]*432
x=[0.8]*432
dT_or= [52]*432
T_a=[20]*432


T_o = []
DT_o = []

# model, here comes the issue
dt = np.arange(30, 431 * 30, 30).reshape(-1)

for step in np.arange(431).reshape(-1):
    if step == 1:
        for i in np.arange(1, dt[step].reshape(-1)):
            DT_o[i] = Dt / k11[step] / tao_o[step] * ((((1 + R_tap[step] * K[step] ** 2) / (1 + R_tap[step])) ** x[step]) * dT_or[step] - (T_oi - T_a[step])) #IndexError here
            T_o[i] = T_oi + DT_o[i]   

    else:
        for i in np.arange(1, (dt[step] - dt[step - 1])).reshape(-1):
            DT_o[i + dt[step - 1]] = Dt / k11[step] / tao_o[step] * ((((1 + R_tap[step] * K[step] ** 2) / (1 + R_tap[step])) ** x[step]) * dT_or[step] - (T_o[i + dt[step - 1] - 1] - T_a[step]))
            T_o[i + dt[step - 1]] = T_o[i + dt[step - 1] - 1] + DT_o[i + dt[step - 1]]

fig_1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(T_o)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

The closest I got to obtaining the same plot is by breaking the expression into list comprehensions, and then extending the range of the variable to be plotted (with another list comprehension), but then the expressions do not seem to be affected by the external loops and do not provide the same Y axis. Below is my reproducible list comprehension attempt:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# model data    
Dt = 1
T_oi = 12
K = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,1.50000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000,0.500000000000000]

k11 = []
tao_o = []
R_tap = []
x = []
dT_or = []
T_a = []

k11=[0.5]*432
tao_o=[210]*432
R_tap=[10.7491679273828]*432
x=[0.8]*432
dT_or= [52]*432
T_a=[20]*432

# dt = np.arange(30, 431 * 30, 30).reshape(-1)

# model
# for step in np.arange(431).reshape(-1):
#     if step == 1:
#         for i in np.arange(1, dt[step].reshape(-1)):
#             DT_o[i] = Dt / k11[step] / tao_o[step] * ((((1 + R_tap[step] * K[step] ** 2) / (1 + R_tap[step])) ** x[step]) * dT_or[step] - (T_oi - T_a[step]))
#             T_o[i] = T_oi + DT_o[i]
#
#     else:
#         for i in np.arange(1, (dt[step] - dt[step - 1])).reshape(-1):
#             DT_o[i + dt[step - 1]] = Dt / k11[step] / tao_o[step] * ((((1 + R_tap[step] * K[step] ** 2) / (1 + R_tap[step])) ** x[step]) * dT_or[step] - (T_o[i + dt[step - 1] - 1] - T_a[step]))
#             T_o[i + dt[step - 1]] = T_o[i + dt[step - 1] - 1] + DT_o[i + dt[step - 1]]


K1 = [x ** 2 for x in K]
R_tap1 = [x * y for x, y in zip(R_tap, K1)]
R_tap2 = [1 + x for x in R_tap1]
R_tap3 = [1 + x for x in R_tap]
R_tap_div = [x / y for x, y in zip(R_tap2, R_tap3)]
R_tap_sq = [y ** x for y in R_tap_div]
T_a1 = [T_oi - x for x in T_a]
R_tap_sq_or = [x * y for x, y in zip(R_tap_sq, dT_or)]
R_tap_tot = [x - y for x, y in zip(R_tap_sq_or, T_a1)]
K11_Dt = [Dt / x for x in np.array(k11)]
K11_Dt_tao = [x / np.array(tao_o) for x in K11_Dt]

DT_o = [x * y for x, y in zip(K11_Dt_tao, R_tap_tot)]
T_o = [T_oi + np.array(x) for x in DT_o]


T_o = [el for el in T_o for _ in range(30)]

fig_1 = plt.figure()
plt.plot(T_o)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Is there a way to optimise list comprehensions or to reformat the loops so to obtain the same plot?

Comment: What does the x-axis you want look like, and what do you get?

Comment: `K = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...,` please convert this into something sensible like `np.array([1, 1.5, 0.5]).repeat(n)`. The same goes for your first loop which seems to just make a bunch of vectors of constants. It's not clear why you need these, but if you really do, don't use a loop! e.g. `k11 = [0.5] * 431`

Comment: `#IndexError here` - why don't you try break that line down into multiple statements to figure out where the index error occurs and for what value of `step` or `i`? Or just use a breakpoint.

Comment: @Dan they are constants obtained from data manipulation in the complete code, I used the loop in the extract so to avoid bringing the whole code here, which is also connected to excel files etc. Your suggestion will make it much tidier, I'll edit it now.. thank you

Comment: @Andrew sorry I meant the Y-axis, dunno what was in my head. X axis is timeline and follows the length of the lists (432), multiplied by 30 in my list comprehension attempt and hence looks correct (as in matlab). Y-axis however is cut at a much lower value then in matlab (20.3 vs 118)